# Fetch the last value of a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to (dynamically) fetch the last value of a range. Therefore I have the following code.

```
Range("C13").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
x1 = Selection.End(xlDown).Select
MsgBox (x1)
```

This however gives TRUE in stead of what I am looking for (the actual value of the cell). Any thoughts on what I should do to get the value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: Related, and good answers in there, duplicate?  IDTS

Answer (score 3):

Replace all your lines with this one:

```
MsgBox Cells(Rows.Count,3).End(xlUp).Value
```

it will return the value of the last cell in column C that has a value.

Answer (score 1):

From Ron DeBruin's site.  I use this all the time.  This is a more reliable way to get the last Row, Column, or cell in a range. using xldown to get to the last row is that with xldown, it will stop at the first blank cell.  .usedrange will catch any ghost formatting that's on the sheet, and can give unpredictable results

```
Function Last(choice As Long, rng As Range)
'Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
' 1 = last row
' 2 = last column
' 3 = last cell
    Dim lrw As Long
    Dim lcol As Long

    Select Case choice

    Case 1:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3:
        On Error Resume Next
        lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                       lookat:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Select
End Function
```

Then call it like this:

```
sub get_the_Last()
dim TheValue as string
dim myRange as range

    set myRange = (assign your range here)
    TheValue = range(Last(3, MyRange)).value 

end sub
```

Comment: It will work, but it's hugely over-complicated for such a simple task.

Comment: @MacroMan I use that "Last" function all the time.  It's not too complicated once it's loaded in, just a simple function call, and it ALWAYS gives the last cell with data

Answer (score -3):

This is how I would have done it

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim x1 As Variant

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

ws.Range("C13").Select

x1 = Selection.Rows(Selection.Rows.Count).Value

MsgBox (x1)

End Sub
```

So Selection.Rows.Count returns the  amount of rows that exist in the selected range.

Alternatively:

```
Sub Test1()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim x1 As Variant

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

ws.Range("C13").Select

MsgBox Selection.Rows(Selection.Rows.Count).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: This will *always* give the value of "C13", and since you only select 1 cell, `Selection.Rows.Count` will *always* be 1.

Comment: Yes of cource it will allways return the value of cell C13. But I haven´t interpreted the question as how do I make a dynamic range?

Comment: Read the question again.  The OP is asking how to get the value of from the *last row in the column that contains the selection*.

Comment: Yes, so if he change what range is selected it will still work. It will allways return the value of the last cell in the selected range.

Comment: How do you propose that he determine what range to select if he doesn't know that the last row is?

Comment: I repeat, the question was not how he determine what range he will be using. The question is based on that he has a dynamic range form which he want the last rows value.
If he need help with determening a dynamic range aswell, that is fine. But that was not what he asked for.

Comment: I guess the point of `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select` eludes me then.

Comment: My last comment now, this adds nothing to the thread.
What Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select would do is select all rows from the previous selected range. I presume OP intended to select the last row in the previously selected range.

Comment: @Henrik that is complete nonsense, you clearly have no understanding of the `xlDirection` enumeration or what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: Also `But I haven´t interpreted the question as how do I make a dynamic range?` - the question clearly states: _(dynamically)_